# What does the message "The master page you have chosen is intended for sites with a version 4 user interface..." mean?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

While selecting a new master page as default in SharePoint Designer I got the below message:

> The master page you have chosen is intended for sites with a version 4
>   user interface. This site's interface is currently set to 15. Would
>   you like to change it to version 4?

I came across similar messages on web, albeit with different version numbers. Almost everywhere it suggested to click on "Yes" and poceed. But I couldn't find what does it mean.

What does the message mean? And if I click on "No" what would be the implications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that this master page was created and configured for SharePoint 2010 (v4, or 14). The site you are trying to apply it on is a SharePoint 2013 site (15).

What the limitations will be is hard to say, as it depends widely on how well written the master page is, but it is always a very good idea to use a masterpage specifically designed for the SharePoint version you are using (15).

Comment: Out of curiosity (and bewilderment), if for SharePoint 2010 its '4' then how come for SharePoint 2013 its '15'?

Comment: Well, that is just one of the Microsoft mysteries ;)